# Python Error [TypeError: 'str' object is not callable] comes up when using input() funtion

Tags: python, input, callable

```
notes =[]

def newNote(notes):

    note = input("Whats up")
    notes.append(note)
    return notes

input = input("in or out? ")

if (input == "in"):

    newNote(notes)
```

`note = input("Whats up")` is the line that has the problem and I see nothing wrong with it. I have tried the line just by instelf (not in a function) and it works but for some reason it doesnt work inside the function.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with line `input = input("in or out? ")`.

You redefine `input` function to result of `input("in or out? ")`, so now the `input` is a string.

The solution is to simply change `input("in or out? ")` result variable to something another:

```py
notes =[]

def newNote(notes):

    note = input("Whats up")
    notes.append(note)
    return notes

choice = input("in or out? ")

if (choice == "in"):

    newNote(notes)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input = input("in or out? ")` is overriding the built-in **input** function.
Replace the variable name with a different name and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
notes =[]
def newNote(notes):
    note = input("Whats up")
    notes.append(note)
    return notes

inp = input("in or out? ")
if (inp == "in"):
    newNote(notes)
```

You have used the keyword 'input' to name a variable. You should never use a keyword to define functions or variables unless you want to override the built in functionality of the language.